# Check a list of users who are online in Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have 1 user and a list of friends of this user in Firestore. How to show this user's friends as online status? If offline will not show

```
User:{
ListFriend:[UserA,UserB,...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firestore does not have any built-in capability to track the user's online status. The closest you can get with purely Firestore is to have each user regularly write a timestamp to the database (which they can only do when they're online), and then have each client determine from that who it considers currently online.

Firebase's Realtime Database *does* have the ability to track when a user disconnects from the server, and perform a (server-side) action in response to that. You can see more about this in its documentation on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) and its [sample presence app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).

There is also documentation on how to combine Firebase's Realtime Database presence system with Firestore. For more on this, see [Build presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). Finally an alpha version of an Extension that encapsulates the same functionality was announced in October 2020, so you might want to check that out in the [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/10/whats-new-at-Firebase-Summit-2020.html).

Comment: i try to use one way is to use react native's NetInfo to check the network connection then if connect then i will update a Field of User(Status), Status object is Online or Offline of User, Is this ok?

Comment: How will you write that the user is offline to the cloud-hosted database, when the user is offline? Btw: if you already tried something and want us to help with that, in the future please post the [minimal reproduction of where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just had that case and it didn't work, User exiting the app doesn't update the status, unless the user loses internet

Comment: i just tried firestore's "detecting connection state" it works fine, but it doesn't detect when the user exits the app

Comment: There are two ways the `onDisconnect` handlers may fire. When the client cleanly disconnects, they fire immediately. When it's a dirty disconnect, the handlers only fire once the server detects that the client is gone, which may take up to a few minutes. If you're having trouble getting this to work, I recommend opening a new question with the [minimal complete code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey @ThắngTrươngKhắc. Anything else needed here?